# How to use Azure Application Insights from an ASP.NET Core Application which is hosted in Linux systemd service

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, systemd

I've created an ASP.NET Core web API that uses Application Insights running on Linux.

Which setting must be made so that my application can also send telemetry data hosted in a Linux service to Application Insights?

**Service**

```
[Unit]
Description=DEPRAG GraphViewer CLOUD API TEST

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/srv/www/test/WebApplication1
WorkingDirectory=/srv/www/test/
KillMode=process
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Programm.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.UseSystemd();
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "THE_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY",
    "ConnectionString": "THE_CONNECTION_STRING"
  }
}
```

If I start the application directly via bash, the transmission of the telemetry works.

I see Live Metrics data in the Azure portal.

If I host the application in a systemd service, the transmission of the telemetry data does not work.

I don't see any Live Metrics data in the Azure portal.
The following message is displayed in the Live Metrics menu item:
Not available: couldn't connect to your application

Comment: Please share your `appsettings.json` and `Program.cs` file.

Comment: In Service file add `Environment` to `Production` and check once.

Comment: I added Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production in service... but still not working:

Comment: Instead of Connection string once try with Instrumentation Key.

Comment: Thank you.
I added InstrumentationKey Key in appsettings.json, but sill not working.

Comment: How you have deployed your App ?

Comment: I used following dotnet command and copied files to the linux machine:
     dotnet publish -c Release -f net7.0 -r linux-x64 --self-contained

As I mentioned before, when I start the Application manually via 
     ./WebApplication1
everything works fine, the telemetry data will be shown in Azure Portal.

Comment: Is your ApplicationInsights enabled in the Azure?

Comment: I think it's not an Application Insights issue. I tried a simple console app which executes a simple async http-call.

It works when I start the app manually in the terminal. But when I start the same app in systemd then I don't get any results. Apparently the async call hangs:

`var result = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.google.de");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252991/discussion-between-donhauro-and-harshitha).

Comment: I think it is a proxy issue. Thank you for your Help.